# How do I get the one-line input in bc?

Tags: bc

I want to have multiple values by the input that space is separating each inputs.

For example, the input `"3 4 5"` lets the value a to 3, value b to 4, value c to 5.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, the read function just have the one-line system. It was such a foolish question!